# Editing an mp4 by manipulating samples

Tags: audio, mp4, video-processing, h.264, aac

I would like to edit/manipulate an mp4 file without decoding/encoding the frames and would like to know if it is possible.

Assume that I have 2 sets of audio/video encoded to exactly the same parameters.

On the video side say I had a sequence of frames like:
IBPPBPPBPPB
and I wanted change this to be (where the -> is what I am inserting)
IBPPB->IBPP

Would this work OK?

I would want to do something similar with the AAC audio by removing/inserting samples.

Comment: It should be possible if you are definately replacing **keyframe + related frames until next keyframe**. The only problem I can think of is maybe the motion vectors might cause "pixel porridge" but I think each keyframe resets them (not confirmed). Best thing is try and then show code when you are stuck on an issue...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible under some circumstances to manipulate the contents of mp4 file without decoding/encoding the frames. For instance, you can split an MP4 file into separate files, or concatenate mp4 files. In general, concatenation works if you have compatible encoding configurations.

For AAC audio streams, there is no decoding dependencies between audio frames so if the streams have the same configuration, you can do editing at the mp4 level without problem.

For video streams, again with the same configuration, you need to concatenate streams starting with random access points (closed gop).

For all these operations, you can use [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

```
MP4Box -split 10:20 file.mp4 -out file-split-10-20.mp4
```

will create a new file containing only 10 seconds.

```
MP4Box -cat file1.mp4 -cat file2.mp4 output.mp4
```

will concatenate two files to produce a new file.